# How to get user input in same line

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to take input with print statement. How take input from the user in same place ?

```
package hello;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Number: ");

        number = sc.nextInt(); 

        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Number Entered: "+number);
    }
}
```

Program output

```
Enter Number: 
10
Number Entered: 10
```

I want to take input in first line

```
Enter Number:  10
Number Entered: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `print()` instead of `println()`.

```
System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java `System.out.println()` means print a line after printing the passed string. Insted of `println()` call another function named `print()` it will just print the string without returning a new line.
So, replace `System.out.println("Enter Number: ");` line into `System.out.print("Enter Number: ");`